# Gitlab ssl in subdomain validation failed

Tags: nginx, gitlab

I want to install gitlab in my nginx server. 
I follow [this instruction](https://about.gitlab.com/install/) for the install.

`gitlab-ctl reconfigure` give me :

```
There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:

letsencrypt_certificate[gitlab.domain.dev] (letsencrypt::http_authorization line 5) had an error: RuntimeError: acme_certificate[staging] (/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/letsencrypt/resources/certificate.rb line 25) had an error: RuntimeError: ruby_block[create certificate for gitlab.domain.dev] (/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/acme/resources/certificate.rb line 108) had an error: RuntimeError: [gitlab.domain.dev] Validation failed, unable to request certificate
```

I use :

- Debian 8
- Nginx
- My firewall allow 443 & 80 (i have one site in http and one in https)
- I have access to sudo (or root)
- `apt install ca-certificates curl openssh-server postfix`

I try :

- Create subdomaine `gitlab.domain.dev` in my dns
- Create SSL cert. for this domain with certbot
- At this step the subdomain is ok
- Install gitlab whit `EXTERNAL_URL="https://gitlab.domain.dev" apt-get install gitlab-ee`
- At this step `gitlab.domain.dev` return nothing
- I test to edit the config file (`nano /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`) like this :

```
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/gitlab.domain.dev/fullchain.pem"
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/gitlab.domain.dev/privkey.pem"
```

- and run `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`
- and catch the error
- i try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51918116/gitlab-self-host-ssl-issues-validation-failed-for-domain) too

I don't understand why i said to tell gitlab to use my ssl certificates already created and how to make my subdomain give gitlab.

My nginx subdomain conf file :

```
# the nginx server instance
server {

    server_name gitlab.domain.dev;
    root /var/www/gitlab.domain.dev;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/gitlab.domain.dev.log;
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/gitlab.domain.dev/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/gitlab.domain.dev/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = gitlab.domain.dev) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name gitlab.domain.dev;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

## update 1

I try :

- convert `.pem` file to `.key` and `.crt` whit :

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in your-cert.pem -out your-cert.crt
openssl pkey -in privkey.pem -out foo.key
```

- change value of gitlab config file `nano /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`  to :

```
nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.domain.dev.crt"
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.domain.dev.key"
```

- reconfigure :

```
There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:

letsencrypt_certificate[gitlab.domain.dev] (letsencrypt::http_authorization line 5) had an error: RuntimeError: acme_certificate[staging] (/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/letsencrypt/resources/certificate.rb line 25) had an error: RuntimeError: ruby_block[create certificate for gitlab.domain.dev] (/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/acme/resources/certificate.rb line 108) had an error: RuntimeError: [gitlab.domain.dev] Validation failed, unable to request certificate
```

Comment: It seems your Gitlab server is configured with letsencrypt configuration. Do you have such line letsencrypt['enable'] = true in you gitlab.rb ?

Answer (score 1):

The setting `letsencrypt['enable'] = false`  used to have a default value set to `false` but later versions of GitLab changed the setting to `true` as a default. The change could break your server script leading to ssl errors such as the one in question.

For my case, I had self signed certificates stored in a specific folder and the default set to true interfered with fetching of self assigned certs. The problem got solved once i changed the setting to `false`

**[Info from official GitLab Docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/ssl.html)**:
"Caution: GitLab 12.1 or later will attempt to renew any Let’s Encrypt certificate. If you plan to use your own Let’s Encrypt certificate you must set letsencrypt['enable'] = false in /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb to disable integration. Otherwise the certificate could be overwritten due to the renewal."